# MySQL Counting matching rows using a JOIN statement

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have two tables `groups` and `users`. I want to write a query that returns the rows from `groups` with an extra column that says how many rows in `users` have a `gid` that matches the `id` of the corresponding group. I have written a query that works fine, except in the case where there are no users in the `users` table with a corresponding `gid`, in which case that `group` is omitted from the result.

```
SELECT a.id, a.admin, a.name, COUNT(b.zbid) users FROM groups a LEFT JOIN users b ON b.gid=a.id
```

How can I get around this? I have worked out that it is definitely the `COUNT` that breaks the functionality. Why? Well if I try the following:

```
SELECT a.id, a.admin, a.name, IF(ISNULL(b.zbid), 0, 1) users FROM groups a LEFT JOIN users b ON b.gid=a.id WHERE a.cid='1'
```

then no rows are omitted, and it will show `users`=1 for any row with corresponding users, and 0 otherwise. However, if I change this to:

```
SELECT a.id, a.admin, a.name, IF(ISNULL(b.zbid), 0, COUNT(b.zbid)) users FROM groups a LEFT JOIN users b ON b.gid=a.id WHERE a.cid='1'
```

then it omits the rows again...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your first query:

```
SELECT a.id, a.admin, a.name, COUNT(b.zbid) as users
FROM groups a LEFT JOIN
     users b
ON b.gid = a.id;
```

You need to include a `group by`, such as `group by a.id` to get counts for all the groups.

I suspect the lack of `group by` is the problem you are facing.